# Select all records that where added less than a month ago and more than a month ago with a score of X

Tags: mysql, sql

From the table below, I'm trying to select records that:

- have been added within the last month (regardless of the score)
- records that are added more than a month ago and have a score of >= 10

My efforts are below, but I'm going wrong somewhere

```
select id from candidates 
where dateEnrolled >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 month) 
and dateEnrolled <= now() and score >=10;
```

I keep getting on `7 and 8`. The right answer should include only the following IDs `1 2 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Can you please help?

```
"id"    "dateEnrolled"  "score"
"1"     "2013-01-01"    "12"
"2"     "2013-02-01"    "15"
"3"     "2013-03-01"    "9"
"4"     "2013-04-01"    "8"
"5"     "2013-05-01"    "20"
"6"     "2013-08-01"    "0"
"7"     "2013-08-12"    "10"
"8"     "2013-08-13"    "12"
"9"     "2013-08-15"    "1"
"10"    "2013-08-17"    "5"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
select id from candidates where dateEnrolled >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 month)
      or (dateEnrolled <= now() and score >=10);
```

Swap your `and` selector for an `or`.

Comment: This works, although I still can't understand how it should be `or` and not `and`. But I'll figure out myself :-)

Comment: records that are added more than a month ago and have a score of >= 10. So shouldnt it be "or (score >=10 and dateEnrolled < date_sub(now(), interval 1 month) )" instead of "or (dateEnrolled <= now() and score >=10)"

Comment: Both conditions are working with the dateEnrolled field although only one of them needs to take the score into consideration. For this condition to work, you will need to split the two conditions using an `Or` instead of and `And`. The moment you use the `And` operator, all conditions need to be true.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id from candidates 
where dateEnrolled >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 month) 
and dateEnrolled <= now() 
or (score >=10 and dateEnrolled < date_sub(now(), interval 1 month) );
```

Comment: What is the extra `and dateEnrolled <= now()` in your sql for?

Comment: To filter future members in selecting members added during last month. In case if you dont have future records it can be removed.